# Deserializing ObjectMeta Regardless of Kind

Tags: go, kubernetes

**TL;DR:** How can I flexibly decode a k8s API object and inspect its top-level `metav1.ObjectMeta` struct without knowing the object's `Kind` in advance?

---

I'm writing an admission controller endpoint that unmarshals a `metav1.AdmissionReview` object's `Request.Object.Raw` field into a concrete object based on the `Request.Kind` field - e.g.

```golang
if kind == "Pod" {
    var pod core.Pod
    // ...
    if _, _, err := deserializer.Decode(admissionReview.Request.Object.Raw, nil, &pod); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    annotations := pod.ObjectMeta.Annotations
    // inspect/validate the annotations...
```

This requires knowing all possible types up front, or perhaps asking a user to supply a `map[kind]corev1.Object` that we can use to be more flexible.

What I'd like to instead achieve is something closer to:

```golang
var objMeta core.ObjectMeta
if _, _, err := deserializer.Decode(admissionReview.Request.Object.Raw, nil, &objMeta); err != nil {
        return nil, err
}

// if objMeta is populated, validate the fields, else
// assume it is an object that does not define an ObjectMeta
// as part of its schema.
```

Is this possible? The k8s API surface is fairly extensive, and I've crawled through the [metav1 godoc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#Object), corev1 godoc & https://cs.k8s.io for prior art without a decent example.

The closest I've found is possibly the [`ObjectMetaAccessor`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ObjectMetaAccessor) interface, but I'd need to get from an `AdmissionReview.Request.Object` (type `runtime.RawExtension`) to a `runtime.Object` first.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can't find what you are looking for because, when decoding an object, Kubernetes uses [GetObjectKind](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/runtime/interfaces.go#L255) and compares the result to a [Scheme](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/runtime/scheme.go#L32) to convert the object to a concrete type, rather than using some [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) like approach and interacting with the fields of an object without knowing it's concrete type.

So you can use reflection instead, something like:

```
k8sObjValue := reflect.ValueOf(admissionReview.Request.Object.Raw).Elem()
k8sObjObjectMeta := k8sObjValue.FieldByName("ObjectMeta")
annotations, ok := k8sObjObjectMeta.FieldByName("Annotations").Interface().(map[string]string)
if !ok {
    panic("failed to retrieve annotations")
}
```

EDIT:

Or closer to your requirements, convert to an ObjectMeta object

```
k8sObjValue := reflect.ValueOf(admissionReview.Request.Object.Raw).Elem()
objMeta, ok := k8sObjValue.FieldByName("ObjectMeta").Interface().(core.ObjectMeta)
if !ok {
    panic("failed to retrieve object metadata")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this that I discovered recently, let me describe it here:

Quick disclaimer: I used admission/v1 and never tested with admission/v1beta1, which should work identically.

The data type of `admissionReview.Request.Object` is `runtime.RawExtension`, and the `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime` provides a method that can convert the `runtime.RawExtension` to a `runtime.Object`. The method is called `runtime.Convert_runtime_RawExtension_To_runtime_Object(...)`. From there, you can easily convert to the `unstructured.Unstructured` data type, which has all the fields from the `MetaV1` object accessible with simple getter methods.

Here is a code snippet that lets you get this accomplished:

```golang
import (
    // ...
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    // ...
)

// ...

func dummyFunc(ar *v1.AdmissionReview) {
    // ...
    var obj runtime.Object
    var scope conversion.Scope // While not actually used within the function, need to pass in
    err := runtime.Convert_runtime_RawExtension_To_runtime_Object(&ar.Request.Object, &obj, scope)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    innerObj, err := runtime.DefaultUnstructuredConverter.ToUnstructured(obj)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }
    u := unstructured.Unstructured{Object: innerObj}
    // Now the `u` variable has all the meta info available with simple getters.
    // Sample:
    labels := u.GetLabels()
    kind := u.GetKind()
    // etc.
    // ...
}
```

References:

1. https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured
2. https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime#Convert_runtime_RawExtension_To_runtime_Object
3. https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/admission/v1#AdmissionRequest

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two possibilities:

1. Either the field `Object` should already contain the correct object instance, when using Go client, check code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/admission/plugin/webhook/request/admissionreview.go#L81).
2. Try using the converters [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/runtime/converter.go)

Comment: Thanks - the challenge is that `*AdmissionRequest.Object.Object` is of type `runtime.Object`, but attempting to create a `meta.Accessor` that then calls `.Annotations(obj)` fails with `object does not implement the Object interfaces`. So although it appears we have the right type, attempting to inspect it _as_ a `runtime.Object` fails.

Comment: Can you show that part of the code? In my experience `meta.Accessor()` from `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/meta` should achieve exactly what you want.